# Can't install app from Play Store (Error Code: -505

Tags: android

I have an app installed in multiple devices running 6.0.1 and 5.1. The package name used is com.mycompany.cricket. This application is not available in Play store.

Now today I published the same app with a different package name - com.mycompany.friskies. If I try to install this app from Play Store then, I get "Error Code: -505" and app doesn't get installed.

If I uninstall the app com.mycompany.cricket from my device, then I can install com.mycompany.friskies from Play Store but lof of our clients are already using com.mycompany.cricket, so we can't tell them to uninstall that and install the new app from Play Store. This app (com.mycompany.cricket) is available from the Beta testing platform TestFairy.

Both of these apps are signed using the same release key.

Please help what could be the reason.